# Pytest & custom exception : TypeError: exceptions must be derived from BaseException, not class 'module'

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, pytest

I cannot seem to get pytest to work on my custom Exception.

Here's the exception code :

```
class FileIsEmptyError(Exception):
    """Raised when the input file is empty"""

    def __init__(self, *args):
        if args:
            self.message = args[0]
        else:
            self.message = None

    def __str__(self):
        if self.message:
            return f"FileIsEmptyError, {self.message}"
        else:
            return f"FileIsEmptyError has been raised."
```

Following the [doc](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/assert.html), here's (simplified) test function :

```
from pyupurs.exceptions import FileIsEmptyError

...

with pytest.raises(FileIsEmptyError):
    raise FileIsEmptyError
```

Here's the unit test's return:

> with pytest.raises(FileIsEmptyError): E       TypeError: exceptions
>   must be derived from BaseException, not class 'module'

Here's the project structure :

```
pyupurs
|---pyupurs
   |---exceptions
      |---__init__.py
      |---FileIsEmptyError.py
   |--- stateless_file_ops
|--- tests
   |--- pyupurs
      |--- stateless_file_ops
         |--- __init__.py
         |--- test_auditing_ops.py
      |--- __init__.py
   |--- samples
      |--- ... 
|--- ...
```

Comment: I think you're only meant to inherit from `Exception`, not from another 'specific' exception. You're not `super`ing `IOError` or using any of it's methods - what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Well I've tried `Exception`, `BaseException` and `OSError`. `IOError` is just a mistake I made while writing this post. Correcting it now.

Comment: Can you show the import statement for `FileIsEmptyError` ?

Comment: I have included the import and project structure in the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

`from pyupurs.exceptions import FileIsEmptyError`

to this

`from pyupurs.exceptions.FileIsEmptyError import FileIsEmptyError`

Comment: Can you please improve your answer with some kind of explanation why this should work?